# Mathematically impossible for a vortex line to have loose ends?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, forces, aerodynamics, flow

[image]

Could someone show the math behind it?

Source :  "A vortex is a bunch of air circulating around itself. The axis around which the air is rotating is called a vortex line. It is mathematically impossible for a vortex line to have loose ends" --- http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-circulation-vortices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vortex is defined as *a region within a fluid where the flow is mostly a spinning motion about an imaginary axis, straight or curved.* Mathematically, this is defined as the [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabla_operator#Curl) of the velocity field, $\mathbf{v}$:
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega}=\nabla\times\mathbf{v}
$$

If we consider the strength of the [vortex tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity#Vortex_lines_and_vortex_tubes) as
$$
\Gamma=\int\boldsymbol\omega\cdot d\mathbf S
$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is the cross-sectional area of the tube, then through [Gauss's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), the above is
$$
\Gamma=\int\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol\omega\,dV
$$
but since the [divergence of the curl is identically zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_of_the_curl), then $\Gamma=0$ which means that the strength of the vorticity is constant everywhere. Since the cross-sectional area cannot decrease to zero, then it must be that the vorticity either terminates at infinity or is a closed loop (this is basically [Helmholtz's second theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz%27s_theorems)).